# tty1 login flashes every few seconds

Tags: login, tty

Running ubuntu server 16.04.2 LTS, and have set up a basic /etc/issue, but the login screen just flashes and refreshes about every 3 seconds or so. It's mildly annoying, but it doesn't really break anything.

Here's my /etc/issue that agetty is displaying at login:

```
^[[0;39;45m^[[3;J^[[H^[[2J
1   \4
2   \6
3   \b
4   \d
5   \s
6   \S
7   \l
8   \m
9   \n
10  \o
11  \O
12  \r
13  \t
14  \u
15  \U
16  \v
```

(The ^[ is just a more readable version of the escape character)

Comment: this actually applies to all terminals, not just tty1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the \4 replacement (show the IPv4 address on the default interface) is what causes the screen to refresh constantly. Removing it solved the problem.